# Do questions about specific conlangs have to be about "published" conlangs?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

For example, if I had been creating Blarth, a conlang, and I had a question--could I ask that question here, or is it limited to conlangs that have been around for a while?

Answer (score 9):

From the [Tour](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/tour):

> Constructed Languages Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for **designers** and users of artificial or invented languages

(emphasis mine).

So, yes, questions about problems you are experiencing creating your own conlang are definitely on topic.

However, if you want a good answer you'll have to provide enough context so that people unfamiliar with your language (just about everyone!) will be able to answer from the information you've provided.

Comment: Okay.  But I do think that we should have a rule that enough context must be provided so that the question can be satisfactorily answered by people who have never seen the language before.

Comment: @CHEESE you're probably right there. Though the usual mechanisms of down-votes and votes to close ("unclear what you asking"?) should suffice in most cases.